# HTC Vive, Unity VR, change acceleration of controllers

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am doing some programming with the HTC Vive in Unity using the SteamVR plugin and I have a simple program where I am hitting boxes around. I now want to add another functionallity but after searching around for an hour I am no closer to figuring out how to approach this.

I want to change the acceleration of the controllers on a specific axis. For example, if I increased the positive Y-axis and flapped my arms up and down, the controllers would end up at head level at one point even though my arms are by my side. How do I do this? Is there a way to change the acceleration for the controllers?

If I can't actually change the acceleration of the controllers, is there a way to change the position of the controller permanently so it doesn't snap back? If so then I could achieve the same effect.

Thanks in advance.